# Desktop background changes to dark gray in activities overview in gnome in 13.04

Tags: gnome, 13.04

Since 13.04, in Gnome, when in activities overview, background changes to dark gray. In 12.10, desktop background would dim but the image would still be visible.

Is this a bug or a feature?

If it is to be expected, OK. But if it is not so, what do I need to do to get the previous behaviour back?

By the way, I am using Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome Shell that ships with it.

Comment: If You using AMD/Intel graphics driver, this can be bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1132033. You can try turn off the file manager handling the desktop (in terminal: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false) - in some cases it helps.